# Replacing Android with Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I would like to replace my current Android system with one connected to Ubuntu. Is that possible?

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in English. I translated your question using Google translate, but it does not make any sense. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be in English and also to make it more specific. Do you want to install Ubuntu on a mobile device? If so, it is probably a duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](//askubuntu.com/q/236276)

Comment: Thanks @Zanna for a more reasonable translation.

Comment: @zanna -- wouldn't be better to leave the original along with the translation text in case the translation is inaccurate. in this case it is spot on but in another it may not be.

Comment: @ravery the original is available in the revision history. In the post, it's just noise. Maybe it would be useful to leave a small note saying that the post was translated

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Depende de qual o hardware que tens. O Ubports tem diversos ports de Ubuntu Touch para diversos equipamentos móveis. Dá uma olhada em https://ubports.com

Hi!

It depends on your hardware. Ubports has several Ubuntu Touch ports to several different mobile equipments. Give a look at https://ubports.com